# XAMPP VM not responding with OSX big sur beta 3

Tags: xampp-vm, macos-big-sur

I just downloaded the MacOS Big Sur Beta 3. The problem is when I'm trying to open XAMPP, you can see the application jumping on the dock but it stops right away without doing any action. Is it possible to access my files without running the XAMPP VM?

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happens to me… Until it gets fixed, you can use the console interface:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ctlscript.sh start
```

Comment: This method can be used to turn on the server modules, but in MacOS Big Sur, it will not work. It will not work on XAMPP VM

Comment: @VikashMishra not sure what you mean by “it will not work”, because I'm literally using it and it works well.